# Removing labels from kinship2 pedigree plot

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm plotting a pedigree for a wild population using kinship2, and trying to remove the labels for individuals. I've tried various arguments in par() and plot() but they either don't get rid of the labels or result in errors. Any ideas?

[image: pedigree plot]

```
ped <- pedigree(id,dadid,momid,sex)
plot.pedigree(ped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can assign blank `""` (or `NA`) to ids when plotting:

```
#Example pedigrees object the manuals
library(kinship2)
data(sample.ped)
pedAll <- pedigree(sample.ped$id, sample.ped$father, sample.ped$mother, 
                   sample.ped$sex,  #affected=sample.ped$affected,
                   affected=cbind(sample.ped$affected, sample.ped$avail), 
                   famid=sample.ped$ped)
ped2 <- pedAll['2']

#assign "" to id argument.
plot.pedigree(ped2, id = rep("", length(ped2$id)))

#or NA
#plot.pedigree(ped2, id = rep(NA, length(ped2$id)))
```

[image]